# SQL Count Distinct Using Multiple Unique Identifiers

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, distinct, aggregate-functions

My company ran a series of TV ads and we're measuring the impact by changes in our website traffic. I would like to determine the cost per session we saw generated, based on the cost of each ad.

The trouble is, the table this is referencing has duplicate data, so my currently **cost_per_session** isn't counting right.

**What I have so far:**

- **client_net_cleared** = cost of ad
- **ad_time, media_outlet, & program** = combined are a unique identifier for each ad
- **diff** = assumed sessions generated by ad

.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tadm.timestamp AS ad_time
, tadm.media_outlet AS media_outlet
, tadm.program AS program
, tadm.client_net_cleared AS client_net_cleared
, SUM(tadm.before_ad_sum) AS before_ad_sessions
, SUM(tadm.after_ad_sum) AS after_ad_sessions
, (SUM(tadm.after_ad_sum) - SUM(tadm.before_ad_sum)) AS diff
, CASE WHEN tadm.client_net_cleared = 0 THEN null
    WHEN (SUM(tadm.after_ad_sum) - SUM(tadm.before_ad_sum)) <1 THEN null
    ELSE (tadm.client_net_cleared/(SUM(tadm.after_ad_sum) - SUM(tadm.before_ad_sum)))
    END AS cost_per_session

FROM tableau.km_tv_ad_data_merged tadm

GROUP BY ad_time,media_outlet,program,client_net_cleared
```

**Sample data:**

```
 ad_time             | media_outlet  | program        | client_net_cleared | before_ad_sessions | after_add_sessions | diff | cost_per_session
---------------------|---------------|----------------|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|------|-----------------
 2016-12-09 22:55:00 | DIY           |                |                970 |                 55 |                 72 |   17 |           57.05
 2016-12-11 02:22:00 | E!            | E! News        |                388 |                 25 |                 31 |    6 |           64.66
 2016-12-19 21:15:00 | Cooking       | The Best Thing |                428 |                 70 |                 97 |   27 |           15.85
 2016-12-22 14:01:00 | Oxygen        | Next Top Model |                285 |                 95 |                148 |   53 |           5.37
 2016-12-09 22:55:00 | DIY           |                |                970 |                 55 |                 72 |   17 |           57.05
 2016-12-04 16:13:00 | Headline News | United Shades  |               1698 |                 95 |                137 |   42 |           40.42
```

**What I need:**
Only count one instance of each ad when calculating cost_per_session.

EDIT: Fixed the query, had a half completed row where I was failing at doing this before asking the question. :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a few rows of input data and a desired result set. Are the rows in your table complete duplicates (in all columns) of each other, or do they differ in some columns?

Comment: Good point! I have provided sample data now. There are rows in the table that are complete duplicates, without difference in any column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `DISTINCT` in `SELECT DISTINCT` in the first line of your query. It makes no sense in a `GROUP BY` query.

If your rows are entirely duplicate, try deduplicating the table before you put it into the `GROUP BY` grinder by replacing

```
FROM tableau.km_tv_ad_data_merged tadm
```

with

```
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT timestamp, media_outlet, program,
                       client_net_cleared,
                       before_ad_sum, after_ad_sum
         FROM tableau.km_tv_ad_data_merged
     ) tadm
```